# Counting the number of occurances of something in the database

Tags: sql-server

For my website, I want to make something that works a bit like the tags on Stackoverflow - so some fields will have an autocompleter, and the autocompleter will display the number of times that other users have selected each suggested value. I suppose I'd have a database structure like this:

```
Articles
    ArticleID
    Content
    TagId

Tags
    TagId
    TagName
    Occurances
```

With the idea being that Occurances represents the number of times each TagId is referenced from the `Articles` table.

What is the best way to implement this?  I could add/subtract from the `occurances` column on each of the stored procedures that update the `article` table, but I might miss one, and anyway, there is are some difficulties with this if a user removes a tag from something (as its easy to add 1 to the field for the newly added tag, but harder to work out which tag is being replaced.)

There is lots I don't understand about sql-server. Is there a more robust way of counting occurances like this, that the database system will deal with itself? It would be ok if the data was cached once a day or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this query to get the number of occurances by tag:

```
SELECT Tags.TagId, COUNT(Articles.TagId) as Occurances
  FROM Articles
  JOIN Tags ON Articles.TagId
  GROUP BY Tags.TagId
```

It could be used in a view or stored procedure, and you can set up your website's cache to requery it as often as required.

Comment: Is it possible to schedule a query like that to run automatically? If I wanted to update the occurances once per day, or once per hour, for instance.

Comment: If you were using ASP.Net, you could for example add the values to the cache with an expiry time span of an hour or a day, then when you come to retrieve the values check the cache, example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhy3h9f9%28v=VS.71%29.aspx - after all, if you know the data has not changed because it is cached, why query the database if you don't have to?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an indexes view that aggregates all the counts you need and is automatically maintained:

```
create view TagCounts 
with schemabinding
as select TagId, count_big(*) as Occurances
from dbo.ArticleTags
group by TagId;
go

create unique clustered index cdxTagCounts on TagCounts (TagId);
go
```

Now the `TagCounts.Occurances` field is automatically maintained by SQL Server whenever you insert/delete/update the `Articles` table. You can query it like:

```
select Occurances from dbo.TagCounts with (noexpand) where TagId = ...;
```

And you can cache the result with [LinqToCache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache), as such a query matches the restrictions of [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx).

The trade off of using a pre-aggregated indexed view is scalability: as update of any article updates the count of Occurances for the tags of the article, an exclusive lock is required to update this count. Which implies that *only one transaction can use a TagId at any moment*. Depending on your traffic and on other elements of your design this restriction may or may not be acceptable.

The other alternative is a table of counts. Front ends (your ASP.Net farm) read this counts and then they update the in-memory count for each operation, keeping track of the delta from the counts in the table. Periodically the front ends merge their deltas into the table (eg. every 5 minutes) and refresh the in-memory table. This way front ends see a stale version of the truth, but an user sees immediate feedback of its actions: because of session stickiness his HTTP requests are processed by the same front end, and thus he see immediately his own article updates triggering modifications to the tag counts.  User though do no immediately see the updates from other users that are load-balanced to another front end. Because a crash of the front end (or a process recycle...) will loose the deltas kept so far, the count table will drift in time away from the truth and would have to be periodically updated to the true count in the database.

If you which even more accuracy (all users see the true count immediately) then you can do something based on fast in-memory key value stores, which would be basically the same as my first proposal but with much higher throughput/lower latency, perhaps something based on [memcached](http://memcached.org/) + [redis](http://redis.io/). I'm not acquainted with SO architecture, but I believe they may be doing [something similar](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2011/04/async-redis-await-booksleeve.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think this will work for me due to the problems you mention: the nature of my website means that articles will be updated very often.

Comment: If you keep your transactions shorts and do a proper design, it *may* sustain update rates of tens-low hundreds per second. You could test it and see if it meets your goals. Is much simpler than any other alternative.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to have more than one tag attached to an article, you will have to add another table that connects the article table to the tag table. It's called a 'many to many' relation.

```
article
  article_id
  content

article_tag
  article_id
  tag_id

tag
  tag_id
  tagname
```

Doing like this, article `1` can be attached to tag `2`, and the next row can be `1` and `3` and so on, so one article points to many tags. To count a certain tag, you join the `Article_Tag` and `Tag` tables, and and count the rows in `Article_Tag` where `Tag.tagname = 'mysql'`, for examle.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I'd have to do something like that eventually. I wanted to keep my question simple though, so listed only two tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a relational database, the correct way to handle this problem is to NOT store the occurrences on the table itself, but rather dynamically query the number of occurrences on the articles table.

If you don't do it this way, you're stuck coding update queries every time you add/delete a row...generally not nice. If you query dynamically, you won't have an occurrences column in the table, but rather will get that information in your eg. presentation/model layer code.

Use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ARTICLES WHERE TagId = 'xxx' ;
```

This line is part of iterating code.

Comment: Think of how the tag system works on stackoverflow, though: It would be querying the database every time the user types a letter into the textbox. It seems to me that counting the occurances each time this happens would be quite expensive. It seems more efficient to cache the count somewhere, and have it updated once an hour, or whenever the database is changed.